# Micronaut @Body coming back a null

Tags: micronaut

With code, the body jsonRequest is not being populated.

```java
@Controller("/query")
public class ApplicationController {

    public JsonDelegate jsonDelegate = new JsonDelegate();
    public ReportDelegate reportDelegate = new ReportDelegate();

    // JSON report.
    @Post(value = "/json/{ReportName}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String json(@Body JSONRequest jsonRequest, @PathVariable("ReportName") String sqlText) {
        return jsonDelegate.view(jsonRequest,sqlText);
    }
}
```

I do have a valid json in the http body section.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you have specified Content-Type header of your POST request?

Comment: I fixed it sort of. This was the problem: -- @PathVariable("ReportName") String sqlText --. When I removed the pathvariable it worked.